# how-to create an insecure jupyter server

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Jupyter only allows access from localhost unless I do a bunch of extra security stuff.  I am running my server so that it is only accessible on a local network where anyone with access is equal in trustworthiness to localhost.  How do I set up a jupyter notebook server with no extra security features?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on your question, I expect you want this configuration (in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`):

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # listen on all IPs
c.NotebookApp.token = ''     # disable authentication
```

There are a few security features in Jupyter (as of 4.3.1). I'll go over how to disable each one, and whether/when it makes sense to disable it:

1. It listens only on localhost. This can be changed to all public IP addresses:

   ```
   c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0'
   ```

   Listening on public IPs should generally come with enabling HTTPS and/or password or token authentication ([docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html)). If it's all internal on a trusted network where nothing bad ever happens, you can proceed to disable other security features:
2. Token authentication is enabled by default. To disable it:

   ```
   c.NotebookApp.token = ''
   ```

   Disabling authentication means that anyone with access to the host can run code. It seems like this is what you want. You can also [enable a password](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/public_server.html#preparing-a-hashed-password):

   ```
   In [1]: from notebook.auth import passwd
   In [2]: passwd()
   Enter password:
   Verify password:
   Out[2]: 'sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed'
   ```

   You can store this in `c.NotebookApp.password`.

   You can also store this password in (`~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.json`):

   ```
   {
       "NotebookApp": {
           "password": "sha1:67c9e60bb8b6:9ffede0825894254b2e042ea597d771089e11aed"
       }
   }
   ```
3. Jupyter also has [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) protections, to avoid other websites from being able to access this server. This means that when a user on your network visits `example.com`, javascript on that page cannot execute code on your notebook server. It sounds like you **don't** want to touch this, but if you are running a service that should be able to access the notebook server, you can add it to:

   ```
   c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = 'https://your.other.host'
   ```
4. Finally, Jupyter 4.3.1 introduces an xsrf token, which is part of dealing with the same category of cross-site execution above. You **don't** need to touch this if users are only accessing the server directly, rather than through javascript on additional websites.

   ```
   c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True
   ```

A *completely insecure* notebook server, which is to say one where any website can run code on it, as long as a browser can connect to its host (this would include localhost or LAN if the browser is running from inside the LAN):

```
c.NotebookApp.ip = '0.0.0.0' # listen on all IPs
c.NotebookApp.token = ''     # disable authentication
c.NotebookApp.allow_origin = '*' # allow access from anywhere
c.NotebookApp.disable_check_xsrf = True # allow cross-site requests
```

This might be desirable if you are aiming to make compute resources free for the world to use however they want via the notebook API.

Comment: In fact, I just needed 1) and 2), but this is a wonderful explanation of jupyter notebook security features.  Thanks much!

Comment: What if I want to listen to different subnets, like `10.90.104.xxx` and `192.168.10.xxx`? What would be the syntax of `c.NotebookApp.ip`?