# Jupyter Notebook rejects cross origin request from localhost

Tags: javascript, jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook running localhost with the following command line:

`jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.token="" --NotebookApp.allow_origin="*" --NotebookApp.open_browser=False`

I now want to access this instance using the Jupyter JavaScript SDK but first I do a simple fetch on the base url to ensure its available:

```
const link = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888';
const response = await fetch(link);
```

However this ends up with the familiar:

*Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource*

I have successfully used the allow_origin flag when accessing remote servers but it doesnt seem to work when running localhost and trying to access from localhost.

Can anyone tell me why that is?

Comment: Generally, CORS requires `https`. See also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233102/how-to-create-an-insecure-jupyter-server

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out I just needed to use something other than the root, so for example *http://127.0.0.1:8888/tree* or *http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab* and then it works fine